# Can you determine an ordinal week in Python similar to datetime's toordinal and fromordinal?

Tags: python, datetime, linear-regression, week-number

I am exploring converting dates to ordinal for regression purposes. I've had success converting my dates to ordinal using datetime.toordinal. Is there such a thing as getting an ordinal week number? So, 737086 represents the 2019-01-03 in the Gregorian calendar. Is there anything that provides an integer week number that spans across the years such as 105298 represents the week 1 (in January 2019)?

The reason I can't use 1-52 is because of the linear regression spanning multiple years. It won't be linear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write some customized function

```
def toordinal(date):
    ((date -  datetime.date.min)/7).days

def fromordinal(n):
    datetime.date.fromordinal(n*7)
```

Comment: I may have tried this incorrectly, but it leads to a decimal and then converting back becomes a problem since I had to truncate the decimal to give me a week.